# openni_tracker on pioneer: illegal instruction

Tags: kinect, ubuntu, pioneer-3dx, ros-fuerte, ubuntu-precise

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi,

I'm trying to use an on-board kinect on a P3-DX pioneer (Cobra EBX-12 Computer) with ros fuerte installed using openni.

The problem appears when I run the openni_tracker node. The node seems to work, but in a few seconds, before it displays any message or something, the message "Illegal instruction (core dumped)" is shown in screen and the node is killed...

I've once fixed [another](http://answers.ros.org/question/42654/openninite-incompatible-in-fuertegroovy-on-precise/) problem when I was trying to run the openni_tracker node in my computer but now, on the robot, the problem seems to be different...

Does anyone know what could be the problem? Could it be related with some computer architecture incompatibility? I downloaded the openni_tracker from the ubuntu repository and I am using ubuntu 12.04 32 bits.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60839/openni_tracker-on-pioneer:-illegal-instruction/) by [arturbp](https://answers.ros.org/users/3069/arturbp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-04-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [arturbp](https://answers.ros.org/users/3069/arturbp/) on 2013-04-16**:
i don't have enough karma to post links, sorry...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you checked the version of NITE that you have downloaded?
I think I had a similar problem when I was using a 64 bit version of Ubuntu and installed the 32 bit version of NITE.

You'll want the x86 version of the NITE release you downloaded.

---

Originally posted by [heyfred](https://answers.ros.org/users/1930/heyfred/) with karma: 122 on 2013-12-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0